# Can I stop my nanopore sequencing run if there are no more reads being produced?

Tags: nanopore, ngs, minion, long-reads, minknow

I am sequencing a whole genome on MinION. I have used this flow cell for 6 hours for the phage lambda control. That gave me around 300,000 reads. I started a 48h sequencing run on the same flow cell after washing it. The sequencing has been going on for 1 day and 21 hours. It is not producing any reads at the moment (Strand = 0). The number of single pores is also 0. Can I "Stop acquisition" without negatively affecting the results?

The image below is a screenshot taken from MinKNOW, the software used to control the MinION.

[image: Pore description and read summary]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can click "stop acquisition" and your run won't be negatively affected. All of the reads are saved as they are generated. I am not sure how this will impact live basecalling though if that is something that you do.

Comment: Live basecalling for the uncalled reads will continue until all have been called, or the application is quit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can stop the run and it should not affect the base calling. We normally do the runs and then do the base calling after the run has completed.